# Drop Duplicate but conserve data in other columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the pandas drop_duplicates method and I'm wondering if I have a table of this form

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 0   A
1   foo 1   A
2   foo 1   B
3   bar 1   A
4   bar 2   A
```

How I can eliminate the duplicate values in a column but keep the data in other columns? So I can get a table as follows

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 0   A
1       1   A
2           B
3   bar 1   A
4       2   A
```

Answer (score 1):

At first use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to check for duplicated values in your dataframe. Then select which columns you want to be changed

```
 is_duplicated = df.apply(lambda x : x.duplicated())
 df_map = df.where(~is_duplicated, '')
 df[['A','B']] = df_map.drop('C', axis=1)
```

Result:

```
     A  B  C
0  foo  0  A
1       1  A
2          B
3  bar     A
4       2  A
```